# Flask: pass to javascript it is in debug mode

Tags: javascript, flask

During development mode of a Flask application, there are many things different compared to production mode, for example connect to a development database instead of the production database.

But also in the Javascript files, some things are different. For example use Google Analytics in development mode.

What is the best way to put the Javascript files into debug mode, without changing them? I would like to have a variable "debug" in Javascript that is either true or false. That variable should be set automatically depending on whether the python app is run in development mode or not.

Hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flask.config object is available in your templates, so you could use an if statement to modify your javascript;

```
<script>
    var debug = false;
    {% if config.debug %}
    var debug = true;
    {% endif %}
</script>
```

Comment: The `tojson` filter would simplify this.